# Is this the best approach using generics to check for nulls?

Tags: c#, generics

```
public static T IsNull<T>(object value, T defaultValue)
{
    return ((Object.Equals(value,null)) | (Object.Equals(value,DBNull.Value)) ?
        defaultValue : (T)value);
}

public static T IsNull<T>(object value) where T :new()
{
    T defaultvalue = new T();
    return IsNull(value, defaultvalue);
}
```

Have tested, and can use against data objects, classes and variables.
Just want to know if there is better way to go about this.

Comment: After reading the other answers, I'm confused. Do you want this method to return true/false (my assumption), or have it return a default value in case of a null ptr?

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you're trying to duplicate the [null coalesce operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
var foo = myPossiblyNullValue ?? defaultValue;
```

Comment: I love this operator, almost as much as the inline-if.

Comment: This is actually the best way to do it.  Although we will be comparing a value type with null if T is a struct or primitive, it does at least give the correct answer.

Comment: @Paul Ruane: keep in mind that the operator only works against nullable types. It makes no sense to even try to look for null on a non-nullable value type.

Comment: @Randolpho For non-nullable types, you can always use `Nullable.GetValueOrDefault(...)` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58x571cw.aspx Of course, this only works if you make your non-nullable type `Nullable<T>` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Comment: @Dan Herbert: you just contradicted yourself. You take your non-nullable type and make it nullable to fit your call to the method.

Comment: @Randolpho I forgot that only works for `Nullable<T>`. I updated my original comment to mention that. The reason why `GetValueOrDefault(...)` would be preferred however is because you can specify an alternate default value, which is what the original question's code was doing. Of course, the coalesce operator will do this as well...

Comment: @Dan Herbert: Exactly. The coalesce operator does everything needed. Plus it's succinct, and no utility code to maintain.

Comment: @Randolpho: my comment was actually against a different snippet.  I'm not sure how your answer changed without leaving a history...

Answer (score 5):

**First off**, the method name is *wrong*. You imply that the result of the function is a boolean that is `true` exactly if the given value is null. In fact, that’s not the case. `GetValueOrDefault` might be a better name.

**Secondly**, you’re merely replicating the behaviour of the null coalesce operator, as mentioned by others.

**Thirdly**, your conditional is odd:

```
Object.Equals(value,null)) | (Object.Equals(value,DBNull.Value)
```

Why `Object.Equals` instead of `==`? Better yet, use `Object.ReferenceEquals` since that makes it clear that you’re interested in reference equality. Also, you’re using the bitwise-or operator (`|`) which is semantically wrong in this context, although it happens to yield the right value. You want the boolean-or operator `||`. (Also, inconsistency: why do you sometimes write `object` and other times `Object`?)

**Finally**, using type `object` instead of a generic type isn’t necessarily a good solution. It would be better to create overloads for generic reference and value types: this avoids boxing in the value types. It also means that you don’t have to specify the type explicitly in your second overload since it can be deduced from the method argument.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static bool IsNull<T>(object value)
{
    return object == default(T);
}
```

Comment: This will return true (is null) for the default value of every value, which is patently wrong as these values are not null.

Comment: Oh, sorry missed the return type.

Comment: Ok, now that I realize how bad this question has been formulated, I go for Konrad Rudolph's answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Edited]

The following (non-generic) should work.

```
    public static bool IsNull(object value) 
    {
        return value == null;
    }
```

Any value type will get boxed (i.e. non-null). Ref types will just be passed by pointer.

Comment: You're missing handling of value types.

Comment: Value types can't be null.  For that, see uvita's answer.

Comment: Obviously they can't, but OP's original method was general, this one is specific to class objects.

Comment: @Paul Ruane, spoulson. thanks for the comments. I still may be wrong as to what the intent is of the IsNull function though.